# How do I change the color and width of material drawer component in angular-dart in css?

Tags: angular-dart

My first question ever - so apologies if I am not specific enough.
How do I change the color and width of material drawer component in angular-dart in css? I have tried it several ways in the CSS, including as below:

```
::ng-deep material-drawer {
  color: #9437FF;
  width: 200px;
}

.material-drawer {
  color: #9437FF;
  width: 200px;
}
```

FYI, the following worked with the material-header, which is inside a header tag:

```
::ng-deep header.material-header.material-header {
  background-color: white;
  color: #9437FF;
}
```

My material-drawer is not in a div or anything, just directly an HTML element on its own.

Any pointers are appreciated!

Comment: "just directly an HTML element on its own." If its not a `<div>` what is is?

Comment: The material-drawer is defined as follows in the html file:

  <material-drawer persistent #drawer="drawer" [visible]="drawerOpen">
    <material-list *deferredContent>
  …

Whereas the material-header is as follows (in a header):
  <header class="material-header">
    <div class="material-header-row"> ...

Answer (score 0):

Setting the width of the drawer is a bit complicated. It involves setting a good amount of values as such it is best to use the mixin. You can see an example [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components_example/blob/cee478667db1ee8bc54f8acc6e4eaf326873d49d/example/app_layout_example/lib/app_layout_example.scss#L24)

As for the color that is a little bit harder. What color are you trying to change? The background color?

For the background color you can set the background-color on the drawer. The problem is going to be that the content itself is going to override that color. In this case the material-list has it's own white color associated with it. Removing that color you could have problems with the divider colors.