# How to change material-drawer background color AngularDart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-html

How can I change the background color of `material-drawer` with AppLayout component of angular_components in an AngularDart project.

app_component.html

```
<material-drawer persistent #drawer="drawer"
                 [class.custom-width]="customWidth">
    <material-list *deferredContent>
        <div group class="mat-drawer-spacer"></div>
        <div group>
            <material-list-item>
                <material-icon icon="inbox"></material-icon>Inbox
            </material-list-item>
            <material-list-item>
                <material-icon icon="star"></material-icon>Star
            </material-list-item>
            <material-list-item>
                <material-icon icon="send"></material-icon>Sent Mail
            </material-list-item>
            <material-list-item>
                <material-icon icon="drafts"></material-icon>Drafts
            </material-list-item>
        </div>
        <div group>
            <div label>Tags</div>
            <material-list-item>
                <material-icon icon="star"></material-icon>Favorites
            </material-list-item>
        </div>
    </material-list>
</material-drawer>
<div class="material-content">
    <header class="material-header shadow">
        <div class="material-header-row">
            <material-button class="material-drawer-button" icon (trigger)="drawer.toggle()">
                <material-icon icon="menu"></material-icon>
            </material-button>
            <span class="material-header-title">Mobile Layout</span>
            <div class="material-spacer"></div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="app-layout">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
        et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
        veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
        legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.

    </div>
</div>
```

app_component.scss

```
@import 'package:angular_components/css/material/material';
@import 'package:angular_components/material_tab/mixins';
@import 'package:angular_components/app_layout/mixins';

:host {

}

.custom-width {
  @include mat-drawer-width(25%);
  @include mat-temporary-drawer-width(25%);

}
```

Comment: See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51308040/how-do-i-change-the-color-and-width-of-material-drawer-component-in-angular-dart/51415254#51415254